# How to convert a BLOB to pdf or csv using itext

Tags: java, javascript, itext

My goal is to display the appropriate file, when the user clicks on a pdf or xls link.
The contents of a pdf or xlsfile are stored as a blob in a table. A stored procedure takes the file id as an input parameter and returns the blob as output.
I want to be able to display the file and am not sure how to go about it. On doing some reading it looks like i could use itest.
Is there a way to convert the blob to a pdf(or xls), using itext. Is this possible?
I was unable to find any examples that use a blob datatype.

Comment: There are a couple of steps to this - basically doing all the database stuff to retrieve the blob, then IO stuff to send get the blob into your HTTP response.  Can you please clarify what you have tried, and what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I am assuming that I have a stored proc that returns a blob for the pdf or csv file. I am not clear how to convert this blob to a pdf or xls file and put it in the response, so that the front end can display it.

Comment: So, do you know how to call the stored procedure?  Do you know how to get the blob from the database when you do?  Do you know how to open an input stream on the blob?  Do you know how to open an output stream on the HTTP response?  Do you know how to copy data from the input stream to the output stream?  Please clarify what you have tried, and what you do and don't know how to do; so that a respondent doesn't need to give you a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment- I know how to execute the stored procedure, get the input stream and also open the output stream on the response. I don't know how to copy the data to the input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(can't comment on David solution due to low reputation)*

If the content on the BLOB record is a PDF binary data, you actually don't need to do anything with iText.

If you are not saving the BLOB to disk before and want (acording to your description) to just display, you could set the content type on the HTTP Response to indicate the browser how to deal with it:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); // for PDF
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); // For BIFF .xls files
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); // For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IOUtils` class in the Apache Commons IO library has a method `copy` which will copy all the bytes from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.  See the [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).

So once you've got your blob and your HTTP response, you can just write

```
OutputStream httpOutputStream = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
InputStream blobInputStream = theBlob.getBinaryStream();
IOUtils.copy(blobInputStream, httpOutputStream);
blobInputStream.close();
httpOutputStream.close();
```

to copy the data.  Or you might want to put the two `close()` calls in a `finally` block.

If you're not already using Apache Commons, don't forget to download the jar and add it to your classpath.